# Getting error while apply ingress resource: zone is too small

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am new to Kubernetes. I have create simple cluster with 1 master and 1 worker nodes(both running in 2 different VMs). Additionally there is HA proxy setup in a separate VM.

```
Client Version: v1.24.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.26.1
```

I have setup NGINX ingress controller using manifests(https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/).
When I try to apply ingress resource with rules I am getting the error:

```
Configuration for default/i1 was added or updated ; but was not applied: error reloading NGINX for default/i1: nginx reload failed: command /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload -e stderr stdout: "" stderr: "2023/02/06 12:49:28 [emerg] 30#30: zone \"default-i1-sim.daniyar.uk-first-web-app-service-80\" is too small in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-i1.conf:4\n" finished with error: exit status 1
```

My ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: i1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sim.daniyar.uk
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: first-web-app-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

IngressClass yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
spec:
  controller: nginx.org/ingress-controller
```

Let me know if you need more info

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

In my case I had to disable zones in NGINX config by using annotation:

```
nginx.org/upstream-zone-size: "0"
```

in my ingress resource file.